# Flyway ignoring sql files

Tags: jenkins-plugins, flyway

I'm using flyway plugin inside jenkins.

I have 3 sql files

1. V1.0__1_C_OWNER.sql
2. V1.1__C_USER_APLICACAO.SQL
3. V1.2__C_DDL_DCL.SQL

Only the first is running by flyway

Jenkins output

```
11:34:23 Flyway Community Edition 5.1.4 by Boxfuse
11:34:23     
11:34:24 Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db1.domain)(PORT = 1523))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = develop))) (Oracle 12.1)
11:34:24 Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.022s)
11:34:24 Current version of schema "U_FLYWAY": 1.0
11:34:24 Schema "U_FLYWAY" is up to date. No migration necessary.
11:34:24 Result is already [Sucess], not changing
```

Plugin config.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting for `sqlMigrationSuffixes` is lowercase `.sql.`.

The suffixes of files 2 & 3 are both uppercase: `.SQL`.

Either rename the files to use a lowercase suffix, or override the default by adding:

```
-sqlMigrationSuffixes=.sql,.SQL
```

to the `Other command line arguments` section in Jenkins.

Answer (score -1):

1. Never edit existing file. Always add a new file and Make sure newly added SQL file Version number is greater than the existing ones.
2. If its a stored procedure make sure you include DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [Procedure_name]; so this enables to delete the old procedure and update with new one.

Comment: Although these are good tips, the answer there is no relation to the question. 1) my examples were 3 versioned files. 2) This is not the problem.